# Cmake Catch2 Link Multiple Libraries containing tests into a Single One

Tags: cmake, catch2

I have multiple child libraries with their own tests cases. I am trying to find a way to combine them together to form a single executable/library that runs all the tests instead of independent ones. However it seems all tests and the runner need to be in the same shared lib or executable, and we can not link multiple libraries together.

For example, in brief I basically have;

```
CMakeLists.txt
   Directory1
      testFile1.cpp
      # Multiple TEST_CASE()s
      CMakeLists.txt
         add_library(libTest1 SHARED testFile1.cpp)
         target_link_libraries(libTest1 PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2)
   Directory2
      testFile2.cpp
      # Multiple TEST_CASE()s
      CMakeLists.txt
         add_library(libTest2 SHARED testFile2.cpp)
         target_link_libraries(libTest2 PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2)
   CombinedTest
      Main.cpp
         int main() { Catch::Session().run(); }
      CMakeLists.txt
         add_executable(testApp Main.cpp)
         target_link_libraries(testApp PUBLIC libTest1 libTest2
                                       PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2)
```

However although this compiles properly, depending on the ordering of the link libraries it will either run the tests in `libTest1` or `libTest2`, but it will not run them both. Both directories are independent and combining them together is not desired we want to keep them separate.

Ideally we would need this as one executable/library that can be run.

Comment: With what command do you run your tests?

Comment: show what you have currently that is working but not yet what you want (a [mre])